# Show that $ p^{(q-1)} + q^{(p-1)}$ is congruent to $1 \hspace{1mm } ($mod $ pq)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Same review sheet, sorry for posting so much. But any help is appreciated.

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct prime numbers. Show that $p^{(q-1)} + q^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm } ($mod $pq)$. (hint: consider $x= p^{(q-1)} + q^{(p-1)}$ modulo $p$ and modulo $q$ separately first.)

Comment: Did you try the hint?  If you change the modulus to $p$, can you prove the congruence you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the Euler theorem we get

$$p^{q-1}+q^{p-1}\equiv q^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$
and similary we have
$$p^{q-1}+q^{p-1}\equiv p^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod q$$
so by the Chinese remainder theorem we get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

By Little Fermat's Theorem, 
$$p^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod q$$
that is, $p^{q-1}-1=mq$. Similarly, $q^{p-1}-1=np$.

Then
$$mnpq=(p^{q-1}-1)(q^{p-1}-1)=kpq-(p^{q-1}+q^{p-1})+1$$